# GCP PubSub - Batching with orderingKey (Nodejs)

Tags: node.js, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

There is an unstable behavior while using **google PubSub batch with orderingKey**.
If I use batch **PubSub without orderingKey**, the code work as expected:

```
        console.log( `Start: [${new Date().toISOString()}]` );
    
        const array = [ ...Array( 5 ).keys() ];
        const topic = pubSubClient.topic( 'topic_test', {
            batching: {
                maxMessages: array.length,
                maxMilliseconds: 10 * 1000,
            },
        } );

        await Promise.all(
            array.map( async ( item ) => {
                const messageId = await topic.publish( Buffer.from( JSON.stringify( item ) ) );
                console.log( `[${new Date().toISOString()}] Message ${messageId} published. id: ${item}` );
            } )
        );
```

I get an immediate result without waiting:

```
Start: [2021-06-22T07:47:01.187Z]
[2021-06-22T07:47:01.187Z] Message 2578553779341346 published. id: 0
[2021-06-22T07:47:01.188Z] Message 2578553779341347 published. id: 1
[2021-06-22T07:47:01.188Z] Message 2578553779341348 published. id: 2
[2021-06-22T07:47:01.188Z] Message 2578553779341349 published. id: 3
[2021-06-22T07:47:01.188Z] Message 2578553779341350 published. id: 4
```

But if I add an orderingKey with batch together:

```
        console.log( `Start: [${new Date().toISOString()}]` );
        
        const array = [ ...Array( 5 ).keys() ];
        const topic = pubSubClient.topic( 'topic_test', {
            enableMessageOrdering: true,
            batching: {
                maxMessages: array.length,
                maxMilliseconds: 10 * 1000,
            },
        } );

        await Promise.all(
            array.map( async ( item ) => {
                const messageId = await topic.publishMessage( {
                    data: Buffer.from( JSON.stringify( item ) ),
                    orderingKey: item,
                } );
                console.log( `[${new Date().toISOString()}] Message ${messageId} published. id: ${item}` );
            } )
        );
```

The batch sent only after 10 seconds (by maxMilliseconds), even though the maxMessages condition has been fulfilled before:

```
Start: [2021-06-22T07:54:31.287Z]
[2021-06-22T07:54:41.995Z] Message 2578621698696149 published. id: 1
[2021-06-22T07:54:41.995Z] Message 2578554178769363 published. id: 4
[2021-06-22T07:54:41.996Z] Message 2578622069514679 published. id: 3
[2021-06-22T07:54:41.996Z] Message 2578621502622110 published. id: 0
[2021-06-22T07:54:42.058Z] Message 2578621667693212 published. id: 2
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

When using ordering keys, batching is done per ordering key. Therefore, if each message has a unique ordering key as is likely in your case, you will always end up waiting `maxMilliseconds`. Typically, there should be some overlap in ordering key, e.g., it should be a user ID or the unique key of a row in a database. Using the entire `item` as the ordering key is unexpected.

Comment: Hi, I used the entire item as the ordering key only for the example. Thank you for the response.